# In Jurassic Park, why did Nedry use this exit plan?

Tags: character-motivation, jurassic-park

### Introduction

Tonight, me and my partner are rewatching Jurassic Park for the third time this year and we started wondering about Nedry's journey to the East Docks.

### Questions

1. **Why DID Nedry turn the other safety systems off? Wouldn't simply overriding the main gate security be enough?**
2. As he hurries through the park, he loses control of the car and rams in to a road sign showing the way to the East Docks. The arrow is then turned, causing him to lose his direction.**Which way should he have turned to get to the East Docks?**
3. **Why did he have to go through the actual park to get to the docks?** (If the answer to that is that no other route existed, **is there a reason for this?**)

Comment: i assume the east docks where to the east, however i could be mistaken, it could have been north, south , or west as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear in what I asked. Have updated.

Comment: Why would Nedry need signs to know the routes, hadn't he been on the island setting up the security for a long time?

Comment: @Oldcat - It was raining, he's stressed, he's never driven himself, etc

Comment: @Oldcat: Nedry was a programmer.  He set up the computer systems, but was unlikely to have actually been in the field setting things up.  He would have **maybe** picked/designed hardware, but the park's engineers would have done the actual installation, especially outside of the Admin buildings.

Comment: Nedry.... or Nerdy?

Comment: Because he's a schmuck

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Why did Nedry shut off the fences?

The [novel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_Park_%28novel%29) covers your first point. In order to gain unfettered access to the **cryo-room** so that he could steal the embryos, Nedry needed to shut down **all** of the security.

> “That's the least of it,” Arnold said. “**When you turn off the
>   security, you turn off all the peripheral fences as well.**” “The
>   fences?” Muldoon said. “The electrical fences,” Arnold said. “They're
>   off, all over the island.”

Note that he could have gotten off the island whenever he wanted (he wasn't a prisoner), but he wanted to do it in a way that offer plausible deniability that it wasn't him that stole the DNA samples. They might *suspect* him of taking the samples but they'd have no outright proof

### Which way should he have gone?

We know that his destination was the East Docks (in the film, to meet the ferry and in the book to meet Dodgson's boat) and we know that he took a wrong turn and ended up being killed by a Dilophosaurus. On the strength of that, I've used the original 'screen-used' [tour map prop](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120609001824/jurassicpark/images/6/60/Jptourmap2.jpg) to show his likely proposed route and likely *accidental* route.

[image]

For the record, in the movie the arrow to the docks originally pointed upwards [shot immediately before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO5j4.png) but was then pointing [to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJBIm.png) in the very next shot, before his car hit the signpost. Under the circumstance, I think we can peg this down to a production error.

### Why did he have to go through the park?

Because the visitor centre is on the West side of the island and the docks are on the East side of the island. In order to travel between these, you need to cross the park however under ***normal*** circumstances you'd only travel alongside enclosures containing relatively benign dinos such as the Stegosaurus, Gallimus and Brachiosaurus.

Comment: A good follow-up question would be, why did he use the jeep to travel along the *visitor road* when the main road would have taken him directly to his destination in half the time.

Comment: Dr. Grant and his tour group were on the main road.

Comment: In the film, the sign points to the left before he hits it. I've no explanation for that other than that it was a production error. There's nowhere on the map that would make sense

Comment: @JoeL. - Good point that man.

Comment: I'm checking the book. The bit with the sign is only in the movie; in the book Nedry just loses his way in a storm. There's no map in the book (at least the one I have), BTW.

Comment: @JoeL. - No, the maps and the layout seem to have been invented for the film.

Comment: In the book at least, Nedry's plan was not to escape with the embryos, but to quickly drop them off at Dodgson's boat unnoticed.  "The whole idea behind the plan was that he could drive to the east dock, drop off the embryos, and be back in a few minutes, before anyone noticed."  Presumably he also shut off security so there would be no evidence, and so he could take a much faster route to the docks.  If he could make it also look like there were no gaps in time  in security videos etc, then he would perfectly avoid suspicion.

Comment: @Kai - A very good point. I presumed that the OP had seen the films but not read the book.

Answer (score 6):

Nedry was *not* planning to leave. He was planning to make it to the east dock, drop off the embryos at the dock, and return.  He figured he would be back so quickly that no one would miss him.

Comment: In the book, this was the case. In the film it wasn't. Since the OP was *rewatching the film*, it might be worth making that clear in your answer

Comment: @Valorum do you mean that Nedry was planning on leaving the island in the book? Because the scene with Dodgson makes it clear that he intends to hand over the embryos to Dodgson man on the boat. ["That's up tp your guy on the boat."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6FXdloCUOM&t=1m39s)

Answer (score -2):

The boat was leaving sooner due to the storm. His quickest route was through the park and perhaps he had to shut the fences down to gain access to this route

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include one or more relevant quotes.